# Why need to ensure gcc's __COUNTER__ macro is not expanded prior to inclusion of precompiled headers which use it?

Tags: c, gcc

I come across following words about [__COUNTER__](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html):

> Care must be taken to ensure that __COUNTER__ is not expanded prior to inclusion of precompiled headers which use it. Otherwise, the precompiled headers will not be used.

I write a simple code to test:

```
$ cat a.h
void func()
{
    printf("%d\n", __COUNTER__);
}
func();

$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", __COUNTER__);
    printf("%d\n", __COUNTER__);
    #include "a.h"
    printf("%d\n", __COUNTER__);
    return 0;
}
```

Build and run it:

```
$ cc a.c
$ ./a.out 
0
1
2
3
```

It works as my expected goal. So how to understand "`Care must be taken to ensure that __COUNTER__ is not expanded prior to inclusion of precompiled headers which use it.`"?

Comment: You should probably spend some time to read about *precompiled headers*, as what you're doing is not involving that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're showing is using a header file normally, it's not using a *precompiled* header. Note that the limitation you're quoting applies to precompiled headers only.

The reason is quite simple, actually: the replacement text of `__COUNTER__` changes each time `__COUNTER__` is expanded. When a header which uses `__COUNTER__` is precompiled, the replacement text(s) valid at the precompilation time will become embedded in the precompiled header.

If you then expand `__COUNTER__` in your code before including the precompiled header, the result of using the header normally vs. precompiled would differ: normal inclusion would use the `__COUNTER__` values as currently modified by the usage before the inclusion, while the precompiled version would contain the replacement text(s) as they were when the header was precompiled. For this reason, the precompiled version cannot be used, since its content would be wrong.